# how to make merge array to single array in php?

Tags: php, json

Sorry, i want to merge two array in to single array. how to merge two array ? thanks for your suggestion code.

```
$data = [{"nama":"mike"}]
$data1= [{"nama":"huna"}]
```

Comment: this is not valid PHP. Please show the real code.

Comment: $data and $data1 is json

Comment: Sure. But that doesn't make for valid PHP. Look, it doesn't compile: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58ef9101518b2a2a506ac360fe5aab058c5ce965 . Are they strings really? And you've missed the `;` off the ends of the lines. Really we could do with valid code to work with, it makes things a lot less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

What you've shown in the question isn't valid PHP. I'm going to assume you actually have two strings like this:

```
$data = '[{"nama":"mike"}]';
$data1 = '[{"nama":"huna"}]';
```

If that's not the scenario then you need to update your question.

Anyway if you have two JSON strings you want to merge, then first decode them into PHP arrays, and then run `array_merge` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php). Then encode the result back into JSON if you need to.

```
echo json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($data), json_decode($data1)));
```

This outputs:

```
[
 {"nama":"mike"},
 {"nama":"huna"}
]
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2bbfe350418a280cb55193369833d4426a9aae7c